# NSBezierPath with rounded rect does not have smooth corners

Tags: swift, core-graphics

I'd like to create a rounded rect similar to the one around the labels (while editing) in AddressBook. I am trying to use a bezierPath with a rounded rect and then stroking it to do this. But, the end result doesn't have very smooth edges.

Address Book label

[image: AddressBook label]

Address Book label zoomed in pixie

[image: AddressBook label zoomed in pixie]

My label

[image: My label]

My label zoomed in pixie

[image: My label zoomed in pixie]

It looks like the curves in the addressbook version are more aggressively mixed towards the background white color. In Pixie, the pixel I have my cursor on has a sRGB value of (0.98, 0.98, 0.98), wheras in my version it is (0.86, 0.86, 0.86) resulting in a bit of jagged edge.
My code to draw the rect is

```
override func drawWithFrame(cellFrame: NSRect, inView controlView: NSView) {
    if let context = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext() {
        context.saveGraphicsState()
        let borderColor = NSColor.init(SRGBRed: 0.75, green: 0.75, blue: 0.75, alpha: 1)
        let outline = NSBezierPath.init(roundedRect: cellFrame, xRadius: 4, yRadius: 4)
        outline.lineWidth = 4
        borderColor.setStroke()
        outline.stroke()

        drawInteriorWithFrame(cellFrame, inView: controlView)
        context.restoreGraphicsState()
    }
}
```

I have tried playing around with different compositing types, line widths and xy radiuses for the round rect - without much success. I would appreciate some guidance on this. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSBezierPath drawing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674118/nsbezierpath-drawing)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this article [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32283/core-graphics-tutorial-lines-rectangles-and-gradients) explains the issue. When we stroke a rect, Coregraphics draws the outline along the middle of the edge of the rectangle we provide. If the rect is 1 pixel wide, then half the stroke line will lie outside the rectangle, while the other half will lie on the inside. As we can't draw half a pixel, Coregraphics mixes the two colors (on the inside and outside) to draw the line. So, to draw a single pixel line, we need to modify the outline rect

```
CGRect rectFor1PxStroke(CGRect rect) 
{
    return CGRectMake(rect.origin.x + 0.5, rect.origin.y + 0.5, rect.size.width - 1, rect.size.height - 1);
}
```

A couple of other options are also provided in the referenced article. But, with my initial testing, the above solution seems to work fine - along with setting the linewidth = 1 and x-y radiuses of the curve to 2

Comment: You might want to check out `CGRectInset`.